# Cannot to connect to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms

Hi I just reading a new book on asp.net that requires me to use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. So I installed the software but when I open it I am ask to give the SQL Server name and when I click browse there is nothing to select.

How can I connect to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Comment: I have installed Visual Studio Profesional and that also installs sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I have installed Visual Studio Profesional and that also installs SQL Server*

So you most likely have a version of SQL Server **Express**, which you can reach if you enter the SQL Server instance name of

```
.\SQLEXPRESS
```

or

```
(local)\SQLEXPRESS
```

Can you connect to SQL Server Management Studio using either of those two server instance names?

The instance might not show up in the browse for servers list because (1) the SQL Server Browser service might not be running, or (2) because the instance has been marked as "hide instance" in the setup.

Answer (score 0):

To install you need to do the following steps:-

Open SQL Server Management Studio, the "Connect to Server" window will open. Select/enter the following:

Server Type: Database Engine

Server Name: `.\SQLEXPRESS`

Authentication: SQL Server Authentication

Login: [SQL 2008 Login name]

Password: [SQL 2008 Password]